# How can I reuse xaml namespace definitions in my project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I reworked this question to show in more detail what I mean by reusing xaml definitions.

```
<UserControl x:Class="XamlDemo.ControlA"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamlDemo"
             xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:XamlDemo.Foo"
             xmlns:bar="clr-namespace:XamlDemo.Bar"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
<!--
    xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:XamlDemo.Foo"
    xmlns:bar="clr-namespace:XamlDemo.Bar"
    foo and bar will tend to repeat in exactly this constellation all over the project.
    If one of these namespaces changes all xaml files need to be edited.
    I would like to include a different file as a component where i would only write foo and bar once
-->
    <StackPanel>
        <foo:ExtTextBlock></foo:ExtTextBlock>
        <bar:ExtLabel></bar:ExtLabel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>


<UserControl x:Class="XamlDemo.ControlB"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamlDemo"
             xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:XamlDemo.Foo"
             xmlns:bar="clr-namespace:XamlDemo.Bar"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <StackPanel>
        <foo:ExtTextBox></foo:ExtTextBox>
        <bar:ExtButton></bar:ExtButton>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

with

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace XamlDemo.Bar
{
    public class ExtButton : Button { }
    public class ExtLabel : Label { }
}
namespace XamlDemo.Foo
{
    public class ExtTextBlock : TextBlock { }
    public class ExtTextBox : TextBox { }
}
```

Both use my local namespace declarations. I would like them to instead include a reference to a different xaml  and get the namespaces from there

I did not find any way of doing this - here is some concept code that illustrates what I imagine this could look like. Obviously this would not compile.

```
<magic
             xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:XamlDemo.Foo"
             xmlns:bar="clr-namespace:XamlDemo.Bar">
</magic>

<UserControl x:Class="..."
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns="get it from magic">
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Are XAML namespaces special in some way? If it's following normal XML rules (which I'd think it should), you should be able to just place those namespace declarations on any *containing* element for those user controls (e.g. find the nearest common ancestor of both). There would then be no need to explicitly reference them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [Freeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979003/freeman), XAML inheritance is not possible. Anyway you can consider using [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for reducing and cleaning the namespace definitions.

You can find an interesting article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and) on CodeProject.

Pratically if the namespaces you want to include in your XAML **are in a refereced assembly**, you can easily map them in a single URI. Just add in the referenced assembly the `XmlnsDefinition` attribute in this way:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("urn:johannes-ui-controls", "XamlDemo.Foo")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("urn:johannes-ui-controls", "XamlDemo.Bar")]
```

and so on.

Then in your XAML you can use them in this way:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:uiControls="urn:johannes-ui-controls">
    <StackPanel>
        <uiControls:ExtTextBox />
        <uiControls:ExtButton />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The limit of this solution is that you cannot use the `XmlnsDefinition` attribute with the assembly which contains your XAML.
Probably this is not exaclty what you meant, but maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Base Control :

```
namespace WpfApplication9
{
    public class BaseControl : UserControl
    {
        public BaseControl()
        {

        }
    public override void EndInit()
    {
        base.EndInit();
        ExtTextBlock block = new ExtTextBlock { Width = 100 , Height = 20 , Text = "Test Block" };
        ExtButton button = new ExtButton { Width = 100, Height = 20 , Content = "ClickMe"};
        ExtLabel label = new ExtLabel { Width = 100, Height = 30 ,Content = "Test Label"};
        ExtTextBox txtBox = new ExtTextBox { Width = 100, Height = 20 ,Text= "Hi There"};
        Grid g = (Grid)BaseControl.FindChild(this, "gridMain");
        g.Children.Add(button);
        g.Children.Add(block);
        g.Children.Add(label);
        g.Children.Add(txtBox);
        Grid.SetRow(block, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(button, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(label, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(txtBox, 3);

        button.Click += button_Click;
    }

    void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi There");
    }

    public static DependencyObject FindChild(DependencyObject parent, string name)
    {
        // confirm parent and name are valid.
        if (parent == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) return null;

        if (parent is FrameworkElement && (parent as FrameworkElement).Name == name) return parent;

        DependencyObject result = null;

        if (parent is FrameworkElement) (parent as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            result = FindChild(child, name);
            if (result != null) break;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Looks for a child control within a parent by type
    /// </summary>
    public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        // confirm parent is valid.
        if (parent == null) return null;
        if (parent is T) return parent as T;

        DependencyObject foundChild = null;

        if (parent is FrameworkElement) (parent as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            foundChild = FindChild<T>(child);
            if (foundChild != null) break;
        }

        return foundChild as T;
    }
}
}

namespace WpfApplication9.Foo
{
    public class ExtTextBlock : TextBlock { }
    public class ExtTextBox : TextBox { }
}

namespace WpfApplication9.Bar
{
    public class ExtButton : Button { }
    public class ExtLabel : Label { }
}
```

Control 1. xaml

```
<base:BaseControl x:Class="WpfApplication9.Control1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:base="clr-namespace:WpfApplication9"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid x:Name="gridMain">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

You can create Control2 class as you create Control1.
As I said xaml inheretence is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I edited the question for clarity. I can not see how I would make your response work - maybe my question was unclear. Can you go into a bit more detail?

Comment: Ah, I see. So you essentially solve this in the code behind part. Not exactly what I was hoping for but it sure makes renaming the dependencies easy.